# Bootstrap Modal only displays backdrop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap to create a modal however it only loads the grey backdrop and not the actual dialog box itself. How can I fix this so the modal displays?

Thanks

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p> Modal </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `jQuery version 3.0.0-alpha` which isn't yet supported by Bootstrap

[image: Error]

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betexo08/2/) I've used your code and `jQuery version 2.1.4` where your modal works as it should.

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0gf329m/) I've used your exact code with `jQuery version 3.0.0-alpha` where it doesn't work

### Solution:

Change your jQuery version from:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!